# how to put search button right side of input box xamarin form?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i have searchbar on top of my page.
by default it's showing in left side of input box as shown in image.
i want to put it in right side of input box 
how to achieve this..?

[image: Searchbutton description]

Here is my code

```
<SearchBar x:Name="searchBar" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  Placeholder="Search text"/>
```

Comment: I sure hope that is not real info in that screenshot..

Comment: @GeraldVersluis i am creating demo apps and using my own info for testing.
Forgot to change in haste :)

Comment: You can refer this link for android: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47727822/how-to-move-search-icon-of-search-bar-at-right-hand-side-in-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

From your image, I think the search icon you have highlighted can only be altered using custom renderers. See

> [How to move search icon of search bar at right hand side in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47727822/how-to-move-search-icon-of-search-bar-at-right-hand-side-in-xamarin-forms)

But, to ignore the search icon and create your own search button beside the searchbar, you can use this:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
<SearchBar x:Name="searchBar" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  Placeholder="Search text"/> 

<Button Text="search"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

By Default, the icon lies on the left side. If you want it on right side , you may have to use a custom search bar